# Error during import (The header record must be an empty or a flat array with unique string values)

Tags: migrations, 9

I want to import some content into my site from a CSV file (bellow) [the file is originally an .xlsx and I use a online CSV converter to get the CSV file)

```
format,type,name,address,id,ttx
open,semi-transparent,Thomas Chao,,rk39k3as22,coming soon
```

And here's my migration file:

```
id: migrate_content
label: 'Import content from CSV to CMS'
migration_group: migration
source:
  plugin: csv
  # Full path to the file.
  path: '/var/www/html/myproject/web/sites/default/files/migrations/test_1.csv'
  header_offset: 1
  ids: [id]
  keys:
    - id
  constants:
    status: 1
process:
  title:
    plugin: create_title
  field_format: format
  field_type: type
  field_name: name
# field_address: address
  field_ttx: ttx
  status: constants/status
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: granularity_type
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

When I run `drush migration:import migrate_content`, I get this error.

> The header record must be an empty or a flat array with unique string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the answer was pretty obvious `header_offset` should be `0`

Comment: Header offset is: `The row to be used as the CSV header (indexed from 0), or null if there is no header row.`. From: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/migrating-data-from-a-csv-source